# Images not appearing after Firebase deploy?

Tags: html, css, firebase, image, deployment

I am updating my online portfolio with a new website (I grabbed a template off Free-Css.com). When I preview it, it works fine. Once I deploy the website via Firebase, none of my images appear.

All of the images are in the public folder, which is where my hosting is set to. Here is an example of one of the images:

```
<div class="col-md-6 about-img-div">
                <!-- <div class="about-border" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay=".5"></div> -->
                <img src="Headshot.jpg" width="400" class="img-responsive" alt="" align="right" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-delay="0" />
```

Even if I use the pull pathname, the images still do not appear. Please note that they do appear if I just open the HTML file, but not while deployed. What am I doing wrong? Here is the website: https://evanmny.com

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yep, you got it. Sorry for the delayed response. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you create/generate the HTML, but when I look at the network tab when loading your site in a browser I see it tries to read this URL:

> https://evanmny.com/Users/evanmullen/Public/city.jpg

That should be:

> https://evanmny.com/city.jpg